# Salesforce DevOps

Tags: cicd

I am new to Salesforce DevOps. Apart from DX and GIT, Can someone help me to know what are the different techonologies can be used to implement a custom SF CICD.

I know how to set up Azure CICD Pipelines, and also how to set up the same using any of the Release Management tools. But I would need help to know the technologies needed for a custom pipeline implementation. Like I have heard that we can set up pipelines using Jenkins? Do we need to use any other tech apart from Jenkins, or Jenkins on its own?

Comment: If you're new to Salesforce, the [Trailhead site](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/sfdx_travis_ci) is a good place to start.

Comment: You can help your question find a good answer, and fit the format of our site, by [edit]ing to add information. What do you know? What have you tried? Where are you stuck? What specific tool or technology are you seeking?

Answer (score 2):

There are not many tools and options - fortunately, or unfortunately.

There is an [Ant-based tool](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.daas.meta/daas/meta_development.htm) that had been the go-to option for migrating metadata. While still supported, you may want to look at Salesforce DX for any DevOps needs today.

Basic toolset -

1. Git for version control
2. SFDX for "doing salesforce stuff"
3. An orchestration engine - Azure Pipelines (or AWS / other alternatives), Jenkins etc. work just fine

Ready-solutions that are easier to get started with are available too - Copado, Flosum, Blue Canvas come to mind.

But, you never quite stop there -

1. Static code analysis through SonarQube, Code Scanner, or simply PMD
2. Incremental deployments are hard - there's an [unofficial Salesforce tool](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2021/01/optimizing-unpackaged-deployments-using-a-delta-generation-tool.html) that can automatically identify differences and generate the file automatically (haven't used it - can't comment)
3. While Apex gets formatted (e.g. loose extra white spaces, etc), you may still want to use specific formatting standards. There's a Prettier Apex plugin to do that. Prettier can help with LWC JS/HTML too
4. SFDX also supports running Apex tests. Work with your favourite testing tool for UI testing - [Selenium](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2020/02/how-to-write-stable-selenium-tests-for-lightning-ui.html) is an option, but there are many many automated testing tools focused on salesforce
5. Do you want to maintain a repository of changes deployed / records of what got in or deleted? Look at integrating Jenkins and tools like JFrog Artifactory

Links that can help-

1. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_ci.htm
2. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=htlHwOPEi58